# Click event when clicking in the DataGridView Background (outside any cell) C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, background, click

I need to focus a Text field everytime the DataGridView is clicked but in the background Area not in a cell or row or column.

Can you guys give me a hand with that. I dont find how this event is called yet, I am using visual studio

thanks a lot!

Comment: Use MouseDown and Hittest!

Comment: are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms application

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample to focus a textbox when the background is clicked and answer your question:

The problem with using the 'Click' event is that it doesn't tell you where the mouse is. You can solve that by using the 'MouseClick' event. Here is one way to receive that event notification:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.MouseClick += DataGridView1_MouseClick;
    }
}
```

Then when the mouse click occurs, you can take your **dataGridView1** control (or whatever it's named) and obtain a Hit Test which gives you information about what Row and Column has been clicked:

```
private void DataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTest = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    string message =
        "Mouse click on " + hitTest.Type.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
        "Row: " + hitTest.RowIndex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
        "Column: " + hitTest.RowIndex.ToString(); 

    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Your question is "how can I tell it's the background area?" In this case you will see 'None' as the Type and the Row and Column index will both be -1:

[image: Show click on Background]

Just look at the **Type** field as shown in the code sample and it will tell you what kind of area that the mouse has clicked. If the **Type** is 'None' focus your textBox1 like this because it's safe to do it this way on the UI thread:

```
if(hitTest.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.None)
{
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
    });
}
```

Hope that seeing this code sample is helpful!